# Best practice for show data inside Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.1

What is the best practice, for example to show user data?

1. Retrieve user in show function inside UserContoller, and pass user variable to the view?
2. Return view in show function, passing the $user_id, and retrieve the user on the view?

Example 1:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('config.users.show')->withUser($user);
}
```

Example 2:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return view('config.users.show')->withId($id);
}
```

Comment: Pass the user to the view. Views should not be running database queries or fetching data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are responsible for data representation.

> A **view** can be any output representation of information, such as a
> chart or a diagram. Multiple views of the same information are
> possible, such as a bar chart for management and a tabular view for
> accountants.
>
> The **model** directly manages the data, logic and rules of the
> application.
>
> The third part, the **controller**, accepts input and converts it to
> commands for the model or view

**[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)**

You should pass the `data` to the view. and output there, So your first example is correct one.

Instead of `withUser()` keep using `with(key, value)`

Example:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('config.users.show')->with('user', $user);
}
```

In view:

```
{{ $user->name }} //assuming user have a name attribute
```

Comment: Thanks! Why `with('user', $user)` instead of `withUser($user)` ?

Comment: Thats how you pass data

Answer (score 1):

Adding to xdevnull's answer, id like to add and share some more information on passing data as when i was first learning laravel this was one the bigger areas i struggled with so i feels you:)

```
return view('config.users.show')->withUser($user);
```

Is a Laravel's dynamic function capabilities which should work.

but personally i prefer the ->with('user',$user); method

then in your blade view:

```
{{$user->propertyname}}
```

I know in your case youre only needing one model, but id thought id share some examples of passing multiple things

Sometimes you find yourself passing more than one model or piece of data:

```
 $user = User::findOrFail($id);
 $someOtherModel = Model::findOrFail($id);
```

in which case you should use the with way and pass an array of your stuff:

```
return view('config.users.show')->with([

    'user'=> $user,
    'otherModel'=>$someOtherModel

]);
```

Then in your view:

{{$otherModel->propertyname}}
{{$user->propertyname}}

and recently i find myself retrieving all results of which id like to be able to use specific ones in different parts of my view. I asked a question regarding this so one of the answers i was given was to make my collection of models into an array. As i said Sometimes you may be retrieving all results and want to pick certain ones by a a specific column or value.

For example i have a model to keep track of site data(phone, address,social media links,etc) and wanted to pass them to my view and access them in specific parts of the page according to their name:

```
$site_meta = \App\SiteMeta::lists('value', 'name');

return view($page_string, compact('site_meta');
```

On my blade template:

```
{{$site_meta['Facebook']}}
```

Hope this helps you somehow, i know it sure did me when i was learning it:)